# Theoretical calculation of probability

Tags: r, binomial-distribution

I am trying to do theoretical calculations for a problem where I have microRNA of size 20, with a probability of 0.7 of getting a purine, if I have 100 of these microRNA what is the probability that the average number of purines will be greater than 15.

I am not allowed to use monte carlo on this.

I had been thinking something along the lines of

```
rbinom(100,20,0.7)
```

but I think that would still be considered a monte carlo? I'm really not sure what direction to go with this.

Comment: Why not use the central limit theorem? You are talking about the sample mean of 100 `bin(20,7)` random variables, and 100 is a fairly large sample size.

Comment: (1) do you really mean *average* number of purines (which implies averaging over several sets of 100), or might you instead mean "number of purines observed in a particular set of 100"? (2) take a look at `?pbinom` ...

Comment: Thank you @JohnColeman! I am very new to CLT and hadn't even considered it.

Comment: I have a suspicion that this a a somewhat simpler version of a question I answered this morning. That question was in turn a follow-up to this question: : "Risk of extinction of Schrödinger's cats"  on the forum where this question _should_ have been asked. Voting to migrate.

Comment: A CLT approach would be a somewhat traditional approach (if by "traditional" you mean doable with a pocket calculator + tables of probabilities), but if every one of the 2000 bases are independent, then your question can be rephrased in terms of a binomial random variable with n = 2000 and p = 0.7, and the R function `pbinom` is perfectly capable of handling that directly.

Comment: Please explain what "not allowed to use monte carlo" means.  If you have a genuine question, why wouldn't you want to employ whatever tool is appropriate and available to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to evaluate

\begin{equation}
  P \left[ \frac{1}{100} \sum_{i=1}^{100} 20 \times I\{\text{RNA}_i = \text{purine}\} \geq 15 \right]
\end{equation}

The mean of your sample is 14. If we let $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{100} \sum_{i=1}^{100} 20 \times I\{\text{RNA}_i = \text{purine}\}$ we can follow the derivation of the weak law of large numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) and provide an upper bound:

\begin{equation}
  P[\lvert \bar{X} - 14 \rvert \geq 1] \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{100} 
\end{equation}

where $\sigma$ is the variance of $20 \times I\{\text{RNA}_i = \text{purine}\} = 84$.